# Recursively locate nested dictionary containing a target key and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

There are many questions about this problem, but in my case they are not working.  I'm trying to find a nested dictionary given a target key and value pair. My recursive function returned none (after fix, max depth recursive error).

```
def recursive_lookup(k, sv, d):
    if k in d: return d[k]
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            a = recursive_lookup(k, sv, v)
            if a == sv:
                if a is not None:
                    return d
    return None


def run():
    maly = {'_id': "ObjectId('5def7e8c4802b906dd067f97')", 'METADATA': {'Tags': {'AcquisitionTime': '2019-02-05T15:59:37.5862118Z', 'ImageScaling': {'ImageScaling': {'ImagePixelSize': '4.54,4.54'}}, 'DetectorState': {'CameraState': {'ApplyCameraProfile': 'false', 'ApplyImageOrientation': 'true', 'ExposureTime': '2200000', 'Frame': '0,0,2752,2208', 'ImageOrientation': '3'}}, 'StageXPosition': '+000000141526.5820', 'StageYPosition': '+000000189329.5000', 'FocusPosition': '+000000002097.2550', 'RoiCenterOffsetX': '+000000000000.0000', 'RoiCenterOffsetY': '+000000000000.0000'}, 'DataSchema': None, 'AttachmentSchema': None}}

    returned_value = recursive_lookup("FocusPosition", "+000000002097.2550", maly)
    print(returned_value)


run()
```

If I change `return d` to `recursive_lookup(k, sv, d)` it is also not working. 
It should return the maly dictionary, but it returned None.

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: what's the dtype of `maly`

Comment: I recommend posting an [mcve] and explaining what this code is supposed to do. Thanks.

Comment: <class 'dict'> @ksooklall

Comment: post edited @ggorlen

Comment: Thanks! Is the desired result supposed to be whichever nested dict contains `"FocusPosition", "+000000002097.2550"` as a direct key-value pair? It's sometimes worth using a simple example that clearly shows the desired behavior using small key/value pairs like `"a"` and `"b"` with a couple simple layers of nesting.

Comment: No it should the dictionary (maly). the d in the recursive function is the dictionary. I search the list of dictionaries with the key (FocusPosition) with the value ("+000000002097.2550"). If the search is correct, I want to have the dictionary. Not the searched Value.

Comment: So just looking at the positive return you return `d`, however in the recursive call you pass `v` as `d` and then it would be sensible to compare it with `v` and not `sv`?

Comment: the search is working properly, if I print d before return. Its the right result. But If I return the d, I get None

Comment: Yeah but the level above that has no way to pass `d` upward through the call stack. I think we're saying the same thing in terms of expected behavior (I hope?)

Comment: I'm guessing it works properly in the call where it is found and fails after the recursion in all the steps because `a` is equal to `d` and not `sv`.

Comment: @madik_atam : in the toy example that I provided in my answer (below) , do you want to return only the value for the matched key, or the whole sub-dictionary where the match is found?

Comment: Oh, I understand. But how this can be fixed now?

Comment: Why do you expect it ever to return `"+000000002097.2550"` in the recursive fucntion?

Comment: I think OP wants the entire containing dictionary. OP already knows the key and value.

Comment: Yes the target is, to get back the entire dictionary, not the searched value.

Comment: Yes and the OP then compares the sub dict with `"+000000002097.2550"` to check if it is a positive result. Won't work. The correct expected result is `None`

Comment: In fact the innner fucntion doesn't return `d` since it returns `d[k]`. That is the real bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right idea, but a matched result isn't being passed up the call stack correctly. You can also simplify logic by checking key and value on the same call frame--this should also eliminate a bug where the target key-value are on the top level of the dict (there's no previous frame to fall back on to check the value).

```
def recursive_lookup(target_key, target_val, dictionary):
    if target_key in dictionary and dictionary[target_key] == target_val:
        return dictionary

    for value in dictionary.values():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            if result := recursive_lookup(target_key, target_val, value): 
                return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    maly = {'_id': "ObjectId('5def7e8c4802b906dd067f97')", 'METADATA': {'Tags': {'AcquisitionTime': '2019-02-05T15:59:37.5862118Z', 'ImageScaling': {'ImageScaling': {'ImagePixelSize': '4.54,4.54'}}, 'DetectorState': {'CameraState': {'ApplyCameraProfile': 'false', 'ApplyImageOrientation': 'true', 'ExposureTime': '2200000', 'Frame': '0,0,2752,2208', 'ImageOrientation': '3'}}, 'StageXPosition': '+000000141526.5820', 'StageYPosition': '+000000189329.5000', 'FocusPosition': '+000000002097.2550', 'RoiCenterOffsetX': '+000000000000.0000', 'RoiCenterOffsetY': '+000000000000.0000'}, 'DataSchema': None, 'AttachmentSchema': None}}
    print(recursive_lookup("FocusPosition", "+000000002097.2550", maly))
```

Here's a more-easily verifiable version that uses a simple dictionary and doesn't use the 3.8 assignment expression:

```
def recursive_lookup(target_key, target_val, dictionary):
    if target_key in dictionary and dictionary[target_key] == target_val:
        return dictionary

    for value in dictionary.values():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result = recursive_lookup(target_key, target_val, value)

            if result: return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dictionary = {
        "a": "foo",
        "b": {
            "c": "bar",
            "d": "baz",
            "e": {
                "f": "quux",
                "g": "garply"
            }
        }
    }

    print(recursive_lookup("c", "bar", dictionary)) # => {'c': 'bar', 'd': 'baz', 'e': {'f': 'quux', 'g': 'garply'}}
    print(recursive_lookup("g", "garply", dictionary)) # => {'f': 'quux', 'g': 'garply'}
```

Comment: in which python version is this solution? I have py3.6 now.

Comment: 3.8. I'll update to 3.6. Let me know if this matches your intent.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code performs a recursive search in a hierarchy of dictionaries. So I guess it may correspond to what you are looking for:

```
def rec_search(key, dic):
  if key in dic:
    return dic[key]
  for d in dic.values():
    if isinstance(d, dict):
      val = rec_search(key, d)
      if val is not None: return val
  return None

maly = {1:'a',
        2:'b',
        3:{4:'d',
           5:'e',
           6:{7:'g',
              8:'h'}
          },
        9:{10:'i',
           11:'j',
           12:{13:'l',
               14:'m'}
          }
        }

print(rec_search(2,maly)) # --> 'b'
print(rec_search(7,maly)) # --> 'g'
print(rec_search(10,maly)) # --> 'i'
print(rec_search(15,maly)) # --> None
```

**EDIT:** Corrected code after Sylwester's comment

Comment: If you have two dicts in the same level you'll return the result form the first regardless if it was positive match or not

Comment: @Sylwester:  Oups! You're totally right. I've corrected the code. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this matches OP's intent. I think OP wants to give a key and a value and get the dictionary that contains that key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is when you call recursive_search() for the second time 
it just keeps looking for sv in the same dictionary which is maly and doesn't search deeper inside the rest that's why it returns None